# Change Scale of Heatmap to Show More Colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I currently have something similar to the below data, with a potentially finer grid. I was wondering if it was possible to make the grid on the `ggplot heatmap` finer? Meaning providing more colours for different values of `z`. As of now, my current plot is mostly 1 colour as they are all between `1e-2` and `1e-5`, but I have one value at `1e-13` and cannot seem to see it at all.

```
x <- seq(3, 5, by = 1)
y <- seq(5, 101, by = 2)
z <- seq(3, 10^-13, length = 146)
### Combinations
combinations <- expand_grid(x, y) %>%
  subset(y > x) %>%
  cbind(z) %>%
  as.matrix()

combinations %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or was that about it?

```
x <- seq(3, 5, by = 1)
y <- seq(5, 101, by = 2)
z <- seq(3, 10^-13, length = 146)

combinations <- expand_grid(x, y) %>%
  subset(y > x) %>%
  cbind(z)

combinations %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, z=z)) +
  geom_contour_filled()+
  geom_point(data = combinations %>% filter(z<1e-6),
             size=10, color = "red")
```

Do it this way. It has to work !!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(3, 5, by = 1)
y <- seq(5, 101, by = 2)
z <- seq(3, 10^-13, length = 146)

combinations <- expand_grid(x, y) %>%
  subset(y > x) %>%
  cbind(z)

combinations %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, z=z)) +
  geom_contour_filled()+
  geom_point(data = combinations %>% dplyr::filter(z<1e-6),
             size=10, color = "red")
```

Comment: Here, I am getting the error `Error in filter.default(., z < 1e-06) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: You have to add `library(tidyverse)` and `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: those are both already installed, the error still occurs.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Is it working now?